# Remove trailing items of two lists if values at the same index are equal

Tags: python, python-2.x, transpose, equality, trailing

I want to accomplish the following:

I have two lists `a` and `b` which are guaranteed to be of size 5. I now want to remove values from the end of both lists that are equal at the same indices / when zipped/transposed. As an example of input and expected output:

```
In:   a=[2,3,2,2,1], b=[2,3,4,1,1]
Out:  a=[2,3,2,2],   b=[2,3,4,1]

In:   a=[9,10,10,10,10], b=[10,10,10,10,10]
Out:  a=[9],             b=[10]

In:   a=[1,2,3,4,5], b=[1,2,3,4,5]
Out:  a=[],          b=[] 
# (a=[1], b=[1] or a=[1,2,3,4,5], b[1,2,3,4,5] are fine as well
#  for this last example, as long as there isn't any error)

In:  a=[10,10,10,10,10], b=[10,10,10,10,9]
Out: a=[10,10,10,10,10], b=[10,10,10,10,9]
```

I know how to remove ***all*** values that are equal at the same indices:

```
f = lambda a,b: [] if a==b else map(list, zip(*[(i,j) for(i,j) in zip(a,b) if i!=j]))[0]
```

Which I can then call as:

```
a,b = [2,3,2,2,1], [2,3,4,1,1]
A,B = f(a,b), f(b,a)
```

But this would result in `A=[2,2], B=[4,1]`, also removing the leading values.

What would be the easiest approach to remove trailing values from both lists until a mismatch is found at the same index?
PS: This is for a [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge. I almost never program in Python, but if I would use it elsewhere I'd probably create variables for the zips instead of this quite unreadable single line I have above. Still, for this answer I would prefer as short as possible answers over readability, although it's not a requirement for this question. Just want to know how to accomplish it in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to use a generator expression to iterate over both lists starting from the end, and keep the first index where a match is found:

```
a=[2,3,2,2,1]
b=[2,3,4,1,1]

ix = next((ix for ix,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(a[::-1],b[::-1])) if i != j), None)
```

Which you can then use to slice the lists (use an if statement to check if the returned values is `None`, which would mean that both lists are equal):

```
if ix:
    print(a[:len(a)-ix])
    print(b[:len(b)-ix])
# [2, 3, 2, 2]
# [2, 3, 4, 1]
```

---

And for your other example:

```
a=[9,10,10,10,10]
b=[10,10,10,10,10]

ix = next(ix for ix,(i,j) in enumerate(zip(a[::-1],b[::-1])) if i != j)

if ix:
    print(a[:len(a)-ix])
    print(b[:len(b)-ix])
# [9]
# [10]
```

Comment: Ah, that looks pretty good. Btw, isn't `i-j != 0` simply `i != j`?

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to work for `a=[10,10,10,10,10], b=[10,10,10,10,9]` (which would mean `a` and `b` remain the same, but their currently resulting in `[]` after the `a[:-ix]` and `b[:ix]`). Forgot about that test case.. Will add it to the question. What would be an easy fix for this?

Comment: Yess true, it has to do with the final slicing. Added a quick fix @KevinCruijssen

Comment: also a `None` default value should be passed to `next` to avoid error when a == b

Comment: Was about to make a comment stating `a[len(a):-ix]` didn't work, but I see you've edited it to `a[:len(a)-ix]` which works like a charm. :) It only doesn't work if both `a` and `b` are completely equal, but that's easy to fix with `[] if a==b else `. Thanks! Will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Yess I'm also updating to fix that, thanks fotr pointing out @LanteDellarovere

Comment: @yatu Ah, perfect. [Seems to work like a charm for all my test cases (after changing `None` to `0` for my use-case).](https://tio.run/##fY/BCoMwEETvfsX2loUVjK0HBb/Co@SQ0EgjNYpEsP35dEWQForswg7DvIGdXuEx@jzGpn7qwdw1aDKVbqsi9XYNQqzQjTOsJBz16DxYvwx21sGKt5sEB6tUKjL7RXQduEvdI2WokoS7oIZWZvS1in6MUiXT7HyARnAcqRGGNB5seYKyccpKyulKNyo27tCnyBbKefindgck639IjB8) :) Accepted, and thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[2,3,2,2,1]
b=[2,3,4,1,1]
```

**solution 1: use while loop**

NOTE : Exception Handling (try-except block),to avoid :IndexError: list index out of range, in special cases like if you have a=[1,2,3,4,5],
b=[1,2,3,4,5]

```
try: 
    while a[-1] == b[-1]:
            a.pop()
            b.pop()
except:
    pass
print (a)
print (b)
```

or

```
while a and a[-1] == b[-1]:
        a.pop()
        b.pop()

print (a)
print (b)
```

Result:

```
in: a=[2,3,2,2,1], b=[2,3,4,1,1]
out: [2, 3, 2, 2],[2, 3, 4, 1]

in: a=[10,10,10,10,10],b=[10,10,10,10,9]
out: [10, 10, 10, 10, 10],[10, 10, 10, 10, 9]

in: a=[9,10,10,10,10],b=[10,10,10,10,10]
out: [9],[10]

in: a=[1,2,3,4,5],b=[1,2,3,4,5]
out: [], []
```

**solution 2: use recursion**

```
def remove(a,b):
    if a[-1] == b[-1]:
        a.pop()
        b.pop()
        return remove(a,b)
    # else:
    #     return

remove(a,b)
print (a)
print (b)
```

> **Python slice()**
>
> The slice() constructor creates a slice object representing the set of
>   indices specified by range(start, stop, step).

```
 a[-1] # return a last element of list
```

> **Python List pop()**
>
> The pop() method removes the item at the given index from the list.
>   The method also returns the removed item.

The syntax of the pop() method is:

```
list.pop(index)

a.pop() # removing last element of list
```

Comment: yes, its necessary for special cases ! if you have : a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3,4,5],  without try-except block you will get: IndexError: list index out of range @Chris_Rands

Comment: i meant `while a and a[-1] == b[-1]:`

Comment: in that case I agree ! :) @Chris_Rands

Comment: Nice answer as well! I think `a and ` should be part of the if in the recursive approach as well, doesn't it? In case `a` and `b` are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over a copy of the list thats is reversed from the original and then iterate over the copy and remove elements from the original like this function:

```
class SomeClass:

def removeSameCharacters(a, b):
    x = a.reverse
    y = b.reverse

    for i in x:
        if x[i] == y[i]:
            a.remove[i]
            b.remove[i]
        else:
            break
```